# Need delete statement for my insert trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following insert trigger which is working fine:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `test1` AFTER INSERT ON `campaign_place`
       FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO campaignplacedenom (id, campaign_id,
       campaignName, place_id, placeName) 

       select new.id, new.campaign_id, campaignName, new.place_id, placeName 

       from campaign pd join place pm on pm.id = new.place_id 

       where pd.id = new.campaign_id
```

But now I have to write a delete trigger which will remove the data from campaignplacedenom table.

Please help as i am very new to mysql.

Thanks

Comment: That isn't a trigger, it's just an insert statement. Could you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? The question isn't too clear, at least not to me.

Comment: @Mureinik...thank you for your response. I actually have this statement in the trigger I have written in Mysql phpmyadmin. its on the AFTER INSERT on the campaign_place table so that the denormalized data is inserted into the campaignplacedenom table.

Now I want to create a Delete trigger and update trigger so that the record is deleted from the campaignplacedenom table as well.

Comment: @Mureinik here is the complete trigger code:
`
CREATE TRIGGER `test1` AFTER INSERT ON `campaign_place`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO campaignplacedenom (id, campaign_id, campaignName, place_id, placeName) select new.id, new.campaign_id, campaignName, new.place_id, placeName from campaign pd join place pm on pm.id = new.place_id where pd.id = new.campaign_id
`

Comment: It's very difficult to read code posted as a comment like this. Please [edit] your post and add the (formatted!) code there.

Comment: @Mureinik....I have edited my original post to show the complete trigger code. Much appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: What problem are you having creating the delete trigger?

Comment: @P.Salmon....I don't know what should be a SQL statement in it.

Comment: The sql statement to delete rows from a tables is Delete